# Need Help Fixing Code for "random crack pairings matchup generator"

Tags: javascript, html, generator

I'm a complete newbie to JavaScript. I'm trying to create a random crack pairings generator that matches names with prompts.

After I added more lists, this stopped working - no prompts or names come up and I can't spot the error.

```
      <!doctype html>

      <html>

<head><title>Crack Pairings Matchup Generator</title>

<script language="JavaScript">
function d(num, sides)
{
    var result = 0;
    for(var i=0; i<num; i++)
    {
        result += 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * sides);
    }
    return result;
}

function init_table()
{
    return [table_1, table_2, table_3, table_4, table_5, table_6][d(1, 6) - 1]();
}

function table_1()
{
    var chars =
                [
                    "",
                  "Jacob",
"Garrus",
"Liara",
"Grunt or DUCK!Grunt",
"Subject Zero",
"Shepard or Both Shepards",
"Saren",
"Kasumi",
"Miranda",
"Mordin",
"Samara",
"Thane",
"Zaeed",
"Collector General",
"Harbinger",
"Oriana",
"Kasumi",
"Tela Vasir" ];
    var choice = d(1, 20);
    if(choice <= 18)
    {
        return chars[choice];
    }
    else if(choice ==19)
    {
        return "(" + table_1() + " + " + table_1() + ")";
    }
    else
    {
        return "(Gender-switched " + table_1() + ")";
    }
}

function table_2()
{
    var chars =
                [
                    "",
"Nihlus",
"Legion",
"Morinth",
"Armando Bailey",
"The Illusive Man",
"EDI",
"Kelly Chambers",
"Kal'Reegar",
"Urz",
"Aria T'Loak",
"Kenneth Donnelly",
"Gabriella Daniels",
"Matriarch Aethyta",
"Doctor Gavin Archer",
"Vigil",
"Sovereign",
"Conrad Verner" ];
    var choice = d(1, 20);
    if(choice <= 17)
    {
        return chars[choice];
    }
    else if(choice ==18)
    {
        return "(" + table_2() + " + " + table_2() + ")";
    }
    else if(choice == 19)
    {
        return "(" + init_table() + " + " + init_table() + ")";
    }
    else
    {
        return "(Gender-switched " + table_2() + ")";
    }

}

function table_3()
{
    var chars =
                [
                    "",
                 "Ashley Williams",
"Kaidan Alenko",
"Urdnot Wrex",
"Udina",
"Rachni Queen",
"Anderson",
"Keeper(s)",
"Tank Bred Krogan",
"Feron",
"Matriarch Benezia",
"Saren Arterius",
"Human reaper",
"James Vega",
"Krogan Princess",
"Kai Leng",
"Strictly!Book Character e.g. Kahlee Sanders/ Skarr/ Edan Had'dah",
"Shepard VI"];
    var choice = d(1, 20);
    if(choice <= 17)
    {
        return chars[choice];
    }
    else if(choice ==19)
    {
        return "(" + table_3() + " + " + table_3() + ")";
    }
    else if(choice == 18)
    {
        return "(" + init_table() + " + " + init_table() + ")";
    }
    else
    {
        return "(Gender-switched " + table_3() + ")";
    }

}

function table_4()
{
    var chars =
                [
                    "",
   "Volus",
"Ambassador Calyn",
"Vorcha",
"Archangle's Squad Mate(s)",
"Mad Prophet",
"Executor Pallin",
"Mechs - LOKI/ FENRIS/ YMIR",
"Gardner",
"Sha'ira",
"Lorik Qui'in",
"Captain Kirrahe",
"Garrus's Flexible Lady-friend",
"Septimus",
"MAKO",
"A clone or AU version of themselves/ itself",
"Citadel Souvenir(s) - fish and/or model ships",
"Any gunship/ starship"];
    var choice = d(1, 20);
    if(choice <= 17)
    {
        return chars[choice];
    }
    else if(choice ==19)
    {
        return "(" + table_4() + " + " + table_4() + ")";
    }
    else if(choice == 18)
    {
        return "(" + init_table() + " + " + init_table() + ")";
    }
    else
    {
        return "(Gender-switched " + table_4() + ")";
    }

}

function table_5()
{
    var chars =
                [
                    "",
"Avina",
"Collectors",
"Thresher Maw",
"Female Alien(s) not appearing in ME2",
"Dr. Amanda Kenson",
"Desolas",
"Emily Wong",
"Anyone/ Everyone in C-Sec",
"Corporal Toombs",
"Legendary or Historical Character e.g. Shiagur",
"Bachelor Party from Eternity",
"Anyone/ Everyone in the Afterlife Club",
"Friendzoned Turian and his Quarian Friend",
"Calibrations",
"Shiala",
"Mercenaries (Blood Pack/ Blue Suns/ Eclipse/ Grim Skulls/ Tiburón Rojo",
"Aleena"];
    var choice = d(1, 20);
    if(choice <= 17)
    {
        return chars[choice];
    }
    else if(choice ==19)
    {
        return "(" + table_5() + " + " + table_5() + ")";
    }
    else if(choice == 18)
    {
        return "(" + init_table() + " + " + init_table() + ")";
    }
    else
    {
        return "(Gender-switched " + table_5() + ")";
    }

}

function table_6()
{
    var chars =
                [
                    "",
                  "Khalisah al-Jilani",
"Kolyat",
"Irikah",
"Patriarch",
"Hannah Shepard",
"Admiral Hackett",
"Gianna Parasini",
"Jessie",
"The entire Reaper Fleet",
"The Council / any Council member",
"Chakwas",
"Joker",
"Space Hamster",
"Veetor'Nara",
"Vido Santiago",
"Blasto"];
    var choice = d(1, 20);
    if(choice <= 16)
{
        return chars[choice];
    }
    else if(choice ==17)
    {
        return "(" + table_5() + " + " + table_5() + ")";
    }
    else if(choice == 18)
    {
        return "(" + table_1() + " + " + table_2() + " + " + table_3() + " + " + table_4() + "+ " + table_5() + ")";
    }
    else if(choice == 19)
    {
        return "(" + init_table() + " + " + init_table() + ")";
    }
    else
    {
        return  "(Gender-switched " + table_6() + ")";
    }

}

function roll()
{
    document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = init_table() + " + " + init_table();
}

function spd()
{
 var chars=
[
"Unrequited love /Jealousy",
“Chuck Norris facts in Soviet Russia”,
"Threesome/ More-some with your character(s) of choice",
"Alternate Universe/ Crossover",
"Drunkenness/ Mass Drunkenness/ the Morning After",
"Snowed in/ Enclosed Spaces ",
“Trapped on a Desert Island / Grounded”,
"Biotics/ Very Roughly",
"In the Afterlife",
"Masturbation/ Caught masturbating ",
"Mind Control/ Indoctrination",
"Aliens Made Them Do It",
"Love/ hate relationship or Hate-sex",
"Virginity/ Beware the Nice Ones", 
"Pregnancy (use male pregnancy if needed)",
“Forced Impregnation e.g. via implantation of parasitical babies”,
"Noncon or Dubcon",
"French maid costume/ Leather/ other clothing kink",
"BDSM/ Spanking/ Sex as Rite-of-Passage",
"Weapon-play e.g. Gunplay or Knife play",
"Pegging/ Frot/ Grinding",
"Doing it in Public/ It’s always the Quiet Ones",
"High school setting/ Everyone as Children",
"Character(s) as Vampire/ Werewolf/ Space Zombies/ Husk/ Any form of Undead",
"Everyone is a furry version of themselves/ As Cat boys & Girls", 
"Species Swap/ Body Swap",
"Hurt/Comfort",
"I Have No Mouth And I Must Scream/ Right Through their Pants or Armour",
"Someone is unconscious, dead or dying/ Johnny Got His Gun",
"Porn Starring in a Video or Magazine",
"Allergic or Hallucinatory Reaction/ It’s Personal",
"Bedtime Story/ Noodle Incident ",
"In the Midst of Battle/ Abandoned Warehouse ",
"Part of a Bargain/ This is Revenge",
"U.S.T/ Morality",
"Someone has or gains an STD",
"With Mass Effect Memes/ Candle Jack kidnaps the reapers and saves the Uni",
"Adoption or Swearing of Brotherhood/ Sisterhood",  
"Strip Dance/ Lap dance/ Stealing Christmas",
"Mistaken identity or gender/ Stolen Identity",
"Murder/ Contract to Kill",
"Tentacles/ Too Kinky to Torture",
"Snuff/ Sexbot/ Kick the Dog",
"Blood play/ Torture/ Orgasm Denial",
"Sports/ Sparring session/ non-lethal Shootout",
"Trollfic/ Stylistic Suck ",
"Mental Illness/ Emotional Trauma/ Brain Bleach",
"69/ Autofellatio",
"Hidden or Unknown Identity/ Gender"
"While Shepard is Driving/ Corruption",
"Someone writes Fan fiction/ Oh Crap There Are Fanfics of Us",
"Virtual sex e.g. by Phone or Hologram(s)",
"Aphrodisiac/ Losing control",
"Someone is sick or injured/ Hot Nurse",
"Body paint/ It’s an Art",
"Direct Nerve Stimulation/ The Hunter Becomes The Hunted",  
"Scat (or scat singing if you’re not up to it)",
"Blind Date or First Date",
"Hacked Implants / Suit(s)/ Armour",
"Carnage fetish / Pyrophilia/ Explosions turn me on",
"Pranks/ Prank Date/ OMG what did I just eat",
"Starting a Relationship to get back at someone",
"While thinking of someone else",
"Planking/ LOLCATS",
"Wedding/ Shotgun wedding ",
"As a Bet/ Meet Cute ",
"Infidelity/ Foot Fetish",
"Memory Loss",
"Meeting the Parents/ All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy",
"Undercover Mission/ Undercover as Lovers, slave/master or Family (Nanny and pets included)",
"Love Triangle / Dodecagon (Imaginary or Not)",
"Secret Relationship/ Relationship Denial",
"Allergic to Love/ Twice Shy/ Love Shy",
"Anguished Declaration of Love",
"Breakup/ Better As Friends (With or Without Makeup)",
"Interruption of: Romance, Sex or Suicide",
"Clueless Magnet/ Eternity ",
"Dancing Together/ Videogame",
"Dying Declaration of Love/ Mistaken for Dying",
"Star Crossed Lovers/ Total Party Kill/ Death by Snu Snu",
"Friends with Benefits/ Gentle Pretence",
"Glomping/ Cuddle Monster",
"Tea Party/ Birthday Party",
"Growing Old together/ Sickeningly Sweethearts",
"Happiness in Slavery/ Bought and Sold as a Slave",
"Home world Visit/ Fandom Bicycle",
"If I Can't Have You — Then No One Else Will!",
"Incompatible Sexual Orientation or Species Orientation (With or Without Emotional Attraction)",
"ON YOUR SIX/ Flank watch/ Loveable Meat shield",
"Love at first: sight/ fight/ voice call or recording",
"Long Distance Relationship/ Force Feeding",  
"Love makes you OOC/ Character Derailment",
"Political Reasons/ Conspiracy",
 “X times they don’t and the one time they do”,
“Kissing/ New Years Kiss/ Kissing it Better”,
"Collar / Leash/ Blindfold",
"Dying of Embarrassment (Literally or Not)",
"Voyeurism/ I like to watch you sleep/ Ceiling Cat",
"Amusement Park/ Zoo/ Circus ",
"Health Check-up/ Health Check-up of the Unmentionables ",
"All involved parties are injured and in Med bay",
"Shore leave/ Holiday celebrations",
"The Musical/ Songfic ",
“Audio Erotica/ Foreign Language”,
“Serenade Your Lover / Bawdy Song”,
“Singing Telegram/ Single Chance”,
"Purple Prose/ Love Poetry",
"Do a Barrel Roll/ Fairy Godparent",
"Pirate-speak/ LOLCAT speak/ Yoda Speak/ 1337 Speak",
"Comparing Scars/ Tales from the Past",
"Asphyxiation (Erotic or Not)",
"My Job Comes First/ Fridge Logic",
"Rescue Romance/ Bad Romance",
"Friendly Fire/ Accident/ Shipwreck",
"Innuendo/ Double Entendre",
"Sexual Predator/ Stalker/ Stalker with a Test Tube for your DNA",
"Cooking/ Culinary disaster",
"Their Parents or Siblings Get Together",
"Back from the Dead (I got better) / Back from the Dead with the Power of LOVE",
"Against All Odds/ Nobody Thinks It Will Work",
“Playing Chicken/ Playing Dead/ Playing Hard To Get",
"I will do ANYTHING for you/ Romantic Hyperbole",
"Pirate/ Ninja/ Cyborg/ Hide and Seek",
"Kidnapped (By somebody inside or outside of the pairing)",
"You’re just a Toy/ the Cake was a Lie",  
"Better Than Sex/ Mary Sueism ",
"Breaking Furniture/ Someone is a Screamer/ Battle Cry",
"Compensating for Something/ Why so Serious?",
"Big or Exotic Equipment/ Help! I'm being repressed",
"Ambiguous in Whether Sex ensued/ G-rated Sex",
"This Isn't What It Looks like",
"Sexism: Fear of Cooties/ Boys are stupid throw rocks at them",
"Sexual Condition e.g. Paraphilias/ Hypersexuality/ Priapism/ Sexsomnia",
"I'm very sensitive/ I didn’t mean to hurt you ",
"Someone Cleans Up Nicely/ Putting On Makeup ",
"Imprisonment/ Separated by the wall",
"Train Station Goodbye/ One Last Fling",
"Matchmaker/ Sarcasm/ Dear Sister ",
"I can Wait/ Worth the Wait/ Missing you",
"NARM/ Smaltz/ Heroic Blue Screen of Death",
"Emo/ Goth/ Preps ",
"No John, you are the demons/ Big Loud Scream/ KHAAAN",
"Courtroom Blues/ Chewbacca Defense”,
 “Funeral/ Funeral Site/ My Heart Will Go On",
"Divorce:  fighting for custody/ All just a Dream (or not)",
"Everyone is Gay or Bi/ Awkward or Fail Sex ",
"Beautiful All Along/ Killing with ugliness",
"Monty Python/ Killer Rabbit/ No one expects the Spanish Inquisition", 
"Pokemon/ the A-Team/ Doctor Who",
"Poking/ Tickling/ Massage",
"THIS IS REVENGE/ S P A R T A",
"Rules of the Internet/ Anything worth doing is worth overdoing",
"As a Poem/ Constrained Writing e.g. Lipogram or Acrostics",
“Kid fic/ Delivery Stork/ Mutant Babies/ Dead baby comedy”,
 “Fluff/ Cuteness Overload”,
“Fix or Wreck Fic/ Nice Job Breaking It, Hero/ It Got Worse”,
“Creative usage/ Refuge in Audacity/ More Dakka”,
“Shower/ Spa/ Onsen”,
“Fairy Tale/ Mind Screw”,
“Secret Diary/ Memoir/ Beyond the Impossible”,
“Misunderstood/ Poor Communication Kills”,
“Salvation/ Mentor/ Berserk Button”,
“The Wind Changed/ Old Wife’s Tale”,
“The fantastical adventures of – “,
“Innocence/ Accidental Pervert”,
 “Big Lipped Alligator Moment/ Only Sane Man/ Redshirts”,
 “Waiting for Godot/ Shakespeare”,
“Abortion”,
“Time Travel/ Time Loop”,
“Precision F Strike/ Blame/ Momma’s Boy or Girl”,
“Retro Glory/ Remembrance”,
“Apologize/ Naked Apologizing”,
“Freedom/ Pride/ Betrayal”,
“Emotionless/ Emotional Vampire”,
“Manipulative Bastard/ Master of Illusion”,
“Bluff/ Bavarian Fire Drill”,
“Sexual Harassment/ Sexual Harassment played as Comedy (e.g. two fat cocks + oil)”,
“Awkwardness/ Hand stuck while-Pick pocketing”,
“Cannibalism/ Food Fetish/ I eat babies”,
“Air quotes/ Hypocrite/ Role-playing”,
“Argument/ It’s MINE and you can’t have it”,
“Sacrifice/ Sacrificial Sock”,
“Physics/ Schroeder's cat”,
“Flopsy/ the Butler Did It”,
 “Hurry up, it’s urgent/ Emergency/ Just in time”,
"Translator Glitch/ Dirty Hungarian Phrasebook",
"Lampshade Hanging/ Epileptic Trees/ Fourth Wall”,
"Verbose/ Shut Up Kiss",
"Spanish Prisoner/ Landmark Sale ",
"Kansas City Shuffle/ Violin Scam”,
"The Rainmaker/ the Sting",
"Cultural Shock/ Misunderstanding"];
    var choice = d(1, 93);
    if(choice <= 93)
    {
        return chars[choice];
    }
    else
    {
        return spd() + " + " + spd();
    }

}

function show_spd()
{
    document.getElementById("spd").innerHTML = spd();
}


</script>

</head>

<body>

<form>
<input type="button" value="Roll" onclick="roll();"></input>
<input type="button" value="Plot Device" onclick="show_spd();"></input>

</form>

<p><div id="results"></div></p>
<p><div id="spd"></div></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Some values use "pretty quotes" instead of `"` for example:

```
“Chuck Norris facts in Soviet Russia”,
```

and there is no `,` after the array value:

```
"Hidden or Unknown Identity/ Gender"
```